# textview is cleaned after rotation in Android 4.0 but not in Android 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-orientation

I have three include other layout (IOL) to include layout with textviews and data in them. Also the background color of the textview changes depending if a related checkbox is checked or not. It happens that if I change device orientation all data and checkboxe states are cleaned, the textview only show the hint text and the background color is conserved. I mention that each IOL include the same layout, but the data in them are accordingly loaded after user selection. I don't understand why **this issue occurs for android 4.0** (and up I think, I didn't test yet) **but it doesn't for android 2.X and 3.X**.
My manifest file has:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" 
        android:configChanges="orientation">
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding this to your manifest, within the relevant activity

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|layoutDirection"
```

I believe it's the 'screenSize' change issue that your dealing with in 4.0 and up.

Answer (score 0):

You Should restore the valure using `SavedInstance` in 4.0 wht you change the rotation of the screen the oncreate method will get called so the values are not saved.

Answer (score 0):

For Honeycomb and up, we mus put:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

this is necessary because the new device technology that could also change its screen size.